# Javadoc for constructor calling on an interface

Tags: java, interface, constructor, javadoc

I have interface called PlayerDatabase and A class called DatabaseUI. Im having problem to write the javadoc, I really don't know how to define what im doing.

```
 public class DatabaseUI {
        private final PlayerDatabase database;
        /**
         * This constructor calls on the database so that the
         * UI can work with it.
         * 
         * @param database contains {@code Player}'s
         */
        public DatabaseUI(PlayerDatabase database) {
            this.database = database;
        }
    }
```

Is this fine javadoc, is this what I am actually doing?

Comment: [EDIT] Deleted for stupidity.

Comment: @FelixMarcus you're missing something rather basic... you can pass objects from classes implementing the interface

Comment: Yup, I'm having an off day it seems. Never mind.

Comment: The DatabaseUI, is just for printing all my cases and taking input from the user. I have another class that implements PlayerDatabase where the stuff actually happens. I just need to call on it so that my UI can work with the database. I dont want to implement the interface cause I don't want to use it's methods. I want my UI to be able to "use" the other class methods, which implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

When writing java docs you don't explain how your code workds this is what comments are for.
Java docs are used for people using your code without knowing or caring how you have implemented it. You need to explain HOW to USE the constructor not how it WORKS. i.e you say what is the expected argument and whatever else user should know about the object the constructor will create

Comment: private final PlayerDatabase database;
    
    /**
     * Calls on the database so that UI can work with it.
     * 
     * @param database contains {@code Player}'s
     */
    public DatabaseUI(PlayerDatabase database) {
        this.database = database;
    }


Like this maybe, Im still new to java and programming and find javadoc really hard. And now Im confused, Am I really calling on the database or am I creating a instance or copy of it?